# Has Spider-Man's spider nature ever emerged to the point that he became dangerous to humans?

Tags: marvel, spider-man

Has Spider-Man's spider nature ever emerged to the point that he became dangerous to humans? Or at least had primitive urges that his human side had to overcome?

Comment: https://villains.fandom.com/wiki/Man-Spider

Comment: What aspect of a spider's nature is dangerous to humans?

Answer (score 9):

In the 90's cartoon, which is the best TV animation he's ever been in<sup>[citation needed]</sup>, he once mutated into [Man-Spider](https://marvelanimated.fandom.com/wiki/Man-Spider):

> Man-Spider was the mutated form of Spider-Man. As explained by Dr. Curt Connors, it was the final stage of Spider-Man's initial genetic mutation.

He ended up looking like this:

[image: Man-Spider, a villainous version of Spider-Man, a six armed humanoid covered in hair with a spider head: 6 red eyes and 4 large fangs: he is still sort of wearing the Spider-Man suit]
<sup>Source: the wiki already linked above</sup>

In this form he was quite dangerous to people:

> Man-Spider is essentially a feral creature. It appears that he lacks higher intelligent functions like speaking. He has some memories from Peter, but they seem relegated to feelings.

The wiki doesn't say much more than this, but I remember he was acting in a threatening manner towards people.

The whole arc involving Man-Spider was about Peter Parker trying to stay human. He eventually gave in to his animal side. Fortunately and with a little help of his friends he eventually reverted back to friendly neighbourhood Spider-Man™. It involved more than willpower though - he did need some biochemical treatment from Dr. Connors.

Answer (score 8):

Primitive urges that his human side had to overcome? That is pretty much the storyline for the issues around issue 19 in *The Spectacular Spider-Man Vol. 2*. Issue 19 starts off with Mary Jane and Aunt May discussing the change in Peter as we see him changing at the same time.

[image: May and Mary Jane discuss Peter and is current problems overlooking a city as we see Peter in an alleyway transforming into a spider amongst the rats and bins]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

With the "help" of Queen he actually ends up completely transforming into a giant spider.

[image: Queen stood in front of Peter who has transformed into a massive spider on a web]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

Of course the initial battle to overcome the primitive side and the mutation occurs earlier but he eventually fixes the problem by birthing himself essentially.

[image: Queen walks away from the body of the "dead" spider Spider-Man, the spider then begins to move and a human Peter is "born" from within it]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

---

There's a nice alternate universe Spider-Man from *Edge of Spider-Verse Vol. 1* issue 4 that is worthy of a mention: Patton Parnel of Earth-51412. After being bit by the radioactive spider he essentially has the ability to kill anyone he pretty much wants to, and he does. His bites also lay eggs in his victims.

[image: Patton launches at his uncle from the ceiling with red eyes, massive teeth and a longue tongue stretching out] [image: The fully transformed Patton (pale, four arms, lots of red eyes and two large fangs) corners Sara Jane in the corner of the room. His uncle is seen still alive on the bed wrapped in a cocoon screaming to be killed as lots of spiders crawl out of him]
<sub>*Click images to enlarge.*</sub>

---

It's not really what you're asking for but I think an honourable mention is Peter Parker of Earth-11080, or the so-called Cannibal Spider-Man from *Marvel Universe Vs. The Punisher Vol. 1*. The Punisher accidentally released Survivor 118 a chemical that was meant to help people adapt to the post-apocalyptic world. However, it instead turned people in cannibals with Spider-Man being the first visible case.

[image: Flashback showing Peter beating the Rhino up before going full on cannibal and starting to eat him on the ice rink of a hockey game. The last panel shows someone watching the TV of the event happening with the Fantastic Four coming in to subdue him]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

Comment: The Edge of Spiderverse kid seems terrifying.  Kinda makes me want to try getting into the comics...  _or_ I could just rewatch Into the Spiderverse again.  That's probably the better option.

Comment: Maybe molting rather than birthing?

Comment: @gatherer818 I think you mean the *easier* option

Answer (score 5):

It depends what you mean by Spider-Man's nature emerging, and which Spider-Man you have in mind. Are you asking whether the 616 Spider-Man ever *naturally* developed primitive, spider-like urges, solely as a result of his spider-powers? If so, then the answer is no.

If you're asking whether something like that has *ever* happened to him, irrespective of the circumstances, then the answer is yes. There are at least three instances of 616 Peter turning into a monstrous 'Man-Spider' as a result of outside influences.

In *[Marvel Fanfare Vol 1 #2](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Marvel_Fanfare_Vol_1_2)*, he was devolved by a genetic transformer built by the mutate, [Brainchild](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Brainchild_(Earth-616)).

[image: Marvel Fanfare v1 002 012]
[image: Marvel Fanfare v1 002 016]
[image: Marvel Fanfare v1 002 017]

In *[Amazing Spider-Man Vol 1 #437](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Amazing_Spider-Man_Vol_1_437)*, he was mutated by mutagenic pollen, courtesy of the super-villain, [Plantman](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Samuel_Smithers_(Earth-616)).

[image: Amazing Spider-Man v1 437 012]
[image: Amazing Spider-Man v1 437 013]
[image: Amazing Spider-Man v1 437 014]

And in *[Spectacular Spider-Man Vol 2](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/The_Spectacular_Spider-Man_Vol_2)* (issues #15-20), he was mutated after ingesting the saliva of the [Spider-Queen](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Adriana_Soria_(Earth-616)) during an involuntary kiss.

[image: Spectacular Spider-Man v2 016 004]
[image: Spectacular Spider-Man v2 019 009]
[image: Spectacular Spider-Man v2 019 010]

Comment: The Animated Series' Man-Spider was a natural development.

Comment: I was talking about 616 Spidey. I'll edit the answer to clarify that.